# Multinomial analysis: two models, different results. What is the correct method in R?

Tags: r, categorical-data, modeling, multinomial-distribution

I'm trying to run multinomial model analysis for my data after a failed oridnal model attempt (model didn't meet proportional odds assumption). My factors are:

1. Response - gameteogenesis stage (4 levels, nominal)
2. Predictor - treatment (4 levels, nominal)
3. Predictor - sex (2 levels, nominal)

So far I've run two models, using two different methods I have found, but I am getting completely different results for each model. The first I used the VGAM package in R with the following code and output:

```
> nommodel2 <- vglm(stage~sex+treatment+sex:treatment, family = multinomial(refLevel=1),data=game)

> Anova(nommodel2, type="II", test="Chisq")

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: stage
              Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)   
sex            4 13.528   0.008964 **
treatment     10 17.818   0.058110 . 
sex:treatment  9  7.280   0.607996   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The second I used the mlogit package with the following output:

```
> multilogitmodel1 <- multinom(stage~sex*treatment, data=game)
# weights:  36 (24 variable)
initial  value 253.691868 
iter  10 value 155.751699
iter  20 value 150.421544
iter  30 value 150.226604
iter  40 value 150.225018
final  value 150.225012 
converged
> Anova(multilogitmodel1, type="II", test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: stage
              LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
sex             49.417  3  1.063e-10 ***
treatment       71.245  9  8.675e-12 ***
sex:treatment   29.061  9  0.0006329 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Basically I'm not sure which model is correct, or how to check the underlying assumptions for these types of models to see if the fit is correct.

I am very new to this type of analysis so any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you write your models mathematically, maybe you can find which model is better.